Vue Router: Force users to change password after first login
Basically, im creating users with a default password and a hasDefaultPassword boolean property set to true and after the login screen i want to force users to change the password and set hasDefaultPassword to false.
Most of this is working, i login and the Change password screen shows up:
async function login() {
    if (await validateLoginForm()) {
        let user = {
            email: email.value,
            password: password.value
        }
        
        ApiHelper.post('user/login', user)
            .then(async (response) => {
                if (response.status == 200) {
                    authStore.saveToken(response.data.userToken, response.data.userForLogin);

                    if(authStore.user.hasDefaultPassword){
                        router.push({ name: 'changePassword' });
                    }else{
                        router.push({ name: 'home' });
                    }
                }
            }).catch((e) => {
                loginErrorMessage.value = e.status == 404 ? e.response.data.message : 'An error occurred. Try again later.';
            })
    }
}

The problem is that its letting me navigate to the other routes, which is something i want to prevent until the password is changed, and i cant figure out how to handle that in the router beforeEach:
const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/login',
      name: 'login',
      component: Login,
      meta: {
        all: true
      }
    },
    {
      path: '/changePassword',
      name: 'changePassword',
      component: ChangePassword,
      meta: {
        admin: true,
        storage: true,
        sales: true
      }
    },
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: Home,
      meta: {
        admin: true,
        storage: true,
        sales: true
      }
    },
    {
      path: '/category',
      name: 'category',
      component: Category,
      meta: {
        admin: true,
        storage: true
      }
    },
    {
      path: '/user',
      name: 'user',
      component: User,
      meta: {
        admin: true
      }
    },
    {
      path: '/:pathMatch(.*)',
      name: '404',
      component: PageNotFound,
      meta: {
        all: true
      }
    }
  ]
})

router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next) => {
  const authStore = useAuthStore();

  if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.all)) {
    next();
  } else if (authStore.user && authStore.user.role.userTypeDescription == 'Admin') {
    if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.admin)) {
      next();
    }
  } else if (authStore.user && authStore.user.role.userTypeDescription == 'Sales') {
    if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.sales)) {
      next();
    }
  } else if (authStore.user && authStore.user.role.userTypeDescription == 'Storage') {
    if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.storage)) {
      next();
    }
  } else {
    next({ name: 'login' })
  }
})

Everything i have tried so far, which was mostly changing the ifs and adding different conditions, breaks the router, causing an infinite loop or an error saying that the next callback was never called.
Any ideas?
Thanks!

I assume you tried some if conditions involving hasDefaultPassword. Can you show what you tried? Seems like if this property is true you should be redirecting users to the changePassword route

I guess you enter a few of those else if but you don't get through the next nested if.
